# Running Nvim-R via PuTTy: setting up r_term_cdm

Tags: r, linux, vim, ssh, putty

I would like to run [**Nvim-R**](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R) on a remote machine via **[putty](/questions/tagged/putty)** when I try to open a `*.R` file the remote machine returns an error message:

> Please set the variable `g:R_term_cmd` in your vimrc. Read the plugin
>   documentation ...

According to the [documentation,](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R/master/doc/Nvim-R.txt) the **`R_term_cmd`** should be used in the following manner:

> If `|R_in_buffer| = 0` and the X Window System is running and **[tmux](/questions/tagged/tmux)** is
>   installed, then R will run in an external terminal emulator. The
>   plugin uses the first terminal emulator that it finds in the following
>   list:
>
> ```
> 1. gnome-terminal,
> 2. konsole,
> 3. xfce4-terminal,
> 4. Eterm,
> 5. (u)rxvt,
> 6. aterm,
> 7. roxterm,
> 8. terminator,
> 9. lxterminal
> ```
>
> 10. xterm.
>
> If Vim does not select your favorite **[terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal)** emulator, you may define
>   it in your `vimrc` by setting the variable `R_term`, as shown below:
>
> ```
>  let R_term = "xterm"
> ```
>
> If your terminal emulator is not listed above, or if you are not satisfied with the way your terminal emulator
>   is called by the plugin, you may define in your `vimrc` the variable
>   `R_term_cmd`, as in the examples below:
>
> ```
> let R_term_cmd = "xterm -title R -e"    
> let R_term_cmd = "xfce4-terminal --icon=/path/to/icons/R.png --title=R -x"
> ```

However, this variable does not appear to be utilised by the sample configuration files available through the [***Vim-R-Tmux: An Integrated Working Environment for R***](http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/programming-in-r/vim-r). Furthermore, the settings in `vimrc`:

```
" start R with F2 key
map <F2> <Plug>RStart 
imap <F2> <Plug>RStart
vmap <F2> <Plug>RStart
" send selection to R with space bar
vmap <Space> <Plug>RDSendSelection 
" send line to R with space bar
nmap <Space> <Plug>RDSendLine
```

## `<LocalLeader>` settings

The suggested `<LocalLeader>` settings not appear to work as pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> does not launch connected R session.

## *Software versions*

```
tmux 2.3
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0
```

Comment: perhaps the issue tracker of Nvim-R is better place to ask?

Comment: @Kent Thanks for showing the interest; my initial view is that my configuration is not right and I'm missing something obvious, not that there is an issue with the `Nvim-R`. I presume that running Nvim-R via is rather common then someone would comment how this should be configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options

### Use Tmux, which you apparently are

This way, Nvim-R can actually use a tmux pane to start an R console.

Please refer to section `9.21 Integration with Tmux` in the documentation.

You need to put the following in your vimrc:

```
let R_in_buffer = 0
let R_applescript = 0
let R_tmux_split = 1
```

### Or just use NeoVim

NeoVim has a builtin terminal, which actually just works with the Nvim-R plugin.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much. I will have a look in a minute. Can I ask whether this would also help to solve the `<LocalLeader>` issue? I was trying to make the *F2* key work as a local leader but it didn't work.

Comment: The localleader is just like leader, for which you set using `let maplocalleader = "'"`. After you do that, you can actually use the builtin mappings, such as `'rf` to start the repl.